# regex match is not as i expect

Tags: java, regex

In the below given Matches:
Why first match is giving that output...
and in second match why '-' is not matched with the target??

```
Index: 01234567890123456789012345678
Target: whois who? Who me? Who else?
Pattern: (^[a-z])|(\?$)
Match: (0,0:w)(28,28:?)

Index: 01234567890
Target: \-^$.?*+()|
Pattern: [\\-^$.?*+()|]
Match: (0,0:\)(2,2:^)(3,3:$)(4,4:.)(5,5:?)(6,6:*)(7,7:+)(8,8:()(9,9:))(10,10:|)
```

Edit:-

Thanks for asking the code

> Please find the code here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/11831819/

Comment: Can you post the pattern as a string? I don't want to type it all myself (and make mistakes)

Comment: regular expression never work as expected on first approach.

Comment: Please provide code example which we could copy and use to reproduce your problem and modify to test our solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one matches any character at the start of the line/string `^[a-z]` and the question mark at the end of the line/string `\?$`, that is because of

- **^** means start of the line
- **$** means end of the line

In the second one, the **[]** means to match characters in the set, and the **-** inside that means "between", so match characters whose ascii value is between **\** (having ascii value 92) and **^** (having ascii value 94), or one of **$.*+()|**. Since the ascii value of **-** is 46, it will not be displayed.

To solve your problem you should quote the `-`

```
[\\\-^$.?*+()|]
```

or put it at the end

```
[\\^$.?*+()|-]
```

. Of course this is bash but:

```
echo 'begin []\^$.?*+()|- end' | sed -e 's/[][\\^$.?*+()|-]/x/g'
begin xxxxxxxxxxxxx end
```

All special characters have been replaced by `x` while I only quoted `\`, because all other chars are placed right. If I move the `-` or the `[` or the `]` I have to quote them too.

Comment: I want to ask u that inside character class [] , only \ and - are the only characters that are treated as meta characters whereas others are treated as non-meta characters.. Is it true

Comment: You can try yourself matching such a string and you should try yourself! Because regular expressions differ in the way how they handle special characters. But inside the class brackets `[]` \- and of course the brackets themselves must be quoted or placed at non suspicious places i.e. the - at the end of the class [] has no meaning, so it's taken as a - without a quote. As I stated above (confirmed by 2): regular expressions never do what you expect on the first approach!